# ADFS 2.0 InvalidNameIDPolicy

Tags: php, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

I've configured an app on the adfs relying party trusts, so I can login using adfs/sso.
After that i'va installed simplesamlphp to deal with that login, and process the response saml.

this is my authsources config:

```
'myauth' => array( 
    'saml:SP', 
    'idp' => 'http://domain/adfs/services/trust', 
    'privatekey' => 'saml.key', 
    'certificate' => 'saml.crt', 
),
```

but after the login, on the return post i get the following error:

> Exception during login: sspmod_saml_Error:
>   Requester/InvalidNameIDPolicy Backtrace: 3
>   /home/......../adfs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:376
>   (sspmod_saml_Message::getResponseError) 2
>   /home/......../adfs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:503
>   (sspmod_saml_Message::processResponse) 1
>   /home/......../adfs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:81
>   (require) 0
>   /home/......../adfs/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:135
>   (N/A)

Am i missing something? How can i get that name id policy? Where to define it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

simplesamlphp normally uses UPN or email as the NameID. You need to check in the config.

So in ADFS, create two claims rules:

One to create the claim (either UPN or email) - the normal LDAP one.

And a Transform that takes the above and transforms to a NameId claim with a type of "transient".

Again, simplesamlphp may not be using transient - you need to check in the config.

**Update:**

Assume UPN:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient");

Comment: This is my rule, atm:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"), query = ";mail,userPrincipalName;{0}", param = c.Value);`

But now i get an sspmod_saml_Error: Responder/RequestDenied

Comment: and i've added this line to the simplesamlphp service: `'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',`

Comment: @nzpcmad when you say "need to check the config", where do you mean? Do you mean the value set for NameIDPolicy in the 'authsources.php' file for the SP?

Comment: Yes - so it looks like you've configured simpleSAMLphp to expect transient. But the rule above doesn't pass NameID - just email and UPN. You still need the transform.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. here's my authsource.php

```'default-sp' => array(
        'saml:SP',
        'privatekey' => 'saml.pem',
        'certificate' => 'saml.crt',
        'idp' => 'http://domain.com/adfs/services/trust',
        'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',```

And the IDP is set to use emailAddress as the NameID.

Comment: This worked for me. I chose UPN along with other items I wanted, in one claim.  Then I created a second custom claim and used the second rule you provided, and everything worked great.  Thanks.