# Requester/InvalidNameIDPolicy Error with SimpleSAMLPHP SP and ADFS IDP

Tags: php, saml, adfs2.0, simplesamlphp

After looking all over the Internet, particularly

- [ADFS 2.0 InvalidNameIDPolcy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816803/adfs-2-0-invalidnameidpolicy)
- [Using SimpleSAMLphp to Authenticate against ADFS 2.0 IdP](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simplesamlphp/I8IiDpeKSvY)
- [Requester/InvalidNameIDPolicy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simplesamlphp/0PtXLkapkA4)

I tried all the suggested modifications to authsource.php and metadata php. Nothing worked.

Here is my authsource.php

```
'default-sp' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'privatekey' => 'saml.pem',
    'certificate' => 'saml.crt',
    'idp' => 'http://domain.com/adfs/services/trust',
```

I used the `XML to simpleSAMLphp metadata converter` to generate the `saml20-idp-remote.php`

So when I access the page, SimpleSAMLPHP correctly redirects me to the IDP login page. I decoded the SAML Request:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="_4e03333c7aa76314d965e05f8fcdd3e1f4c5be96c8" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2014-12-11T19:41:50Z" 
    Destination="https://domain.com/adfs/ls/" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://sub.domain.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST">

    <saml:Issuer>
        https://su.bdomain.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp
    </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/>

</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

After logging in with a valid test account, I'm redirected back to my site with the error.

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
0 /var/www/html/igt_s3k/web/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:179 (N/A)
Caused by: sspmod_saml_Error: Requester/InvalidNameIDPolicy
Backtrace:
3 /var/www/html/igt_s3k/web/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:385 (sspmod_saml_Message::getResponseError)
2 /var/www/html/igt_s3k/web/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:495 (sspmod_saml_Message::processResponse)
1 /var/www/html/igt_s3k/web/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:96 (require)
0 /var/www/html/igt_s3k/web/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:134 (N/A)
```

I tried setting different NameIDPolicy but none of them worked.

```
    //'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
    //'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',
    //'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
    //'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
```

Thanks!

Comment: I was getting a similar error for having 'store.type' => 'memcache', instead of phpsession

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of SimpleSAML v1.15.0, setting the `NameIDPolicy` to `NULL` is not supported, and will result in an error.

If you do not set the NameIDPolicy, the SAML Request will default to:  `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient`, which can cause integration problems.

In order to not explictly send the NameIDPolicy in the auth request, apply the patch found [here](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/771), and set the NameIDPolicy to false in the authsources.php config file.

```
'NameIDPolicy' => false
```

Comment: After applying the patch in Message.php and setting the NameIDPolicy to FALSE worked for me, also we need to make sure we have a proper privatekey and certificate file for the signing

Comment: this is the valid answer now

Comment: Just as a note: This option has to be set in the `config/authsources.php` within the configuration of your SP (see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451231/336311).

Comment: Thanks @BurninLeo - I have edited the answer to add that information too.

Answer (score 22):

Yeah. In a fit of anger and frustration. I set NameIDPolicy to null and everything works. FML

```
'default-sp' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'privatekey' => 'saml.pem',
    'certificate' => 'saml.crt',
    'idp' => 'http://comain.com/adfs/services/trust',
    'NameIDPolicy' => null,
```

Comment: @YarGnawh You just saved me so much time and energy! Thank you so much! Works with Moodle/saml2 Auth plugin, if anyone is hitting the same spot I did.

Comment: Great thanks. This bug still exists in the latest simplesamlphp on github June 2016

Comment: I am another one of those people you just saved a bunch of time - Thank you !

Comment: First thing I Googled. I'm wondering how long I would have burnt on this

Comment: According to https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/771#issuecomment-433412601 you should set it to `false` with modern SimpleSAML version.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4038.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-request-a-specific-name-id-format-from-a-claims-provider-cp-during-saml-2-0-single-sign-on-sso.aspx
you should use the default value of unspecified
'NameIDPolicy' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',

Comment: After adding 'unspecified' as suggested here, once I got the attributes response i could see it said the NameId had `Format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress`

So I just added this as the new NameIdPolicy (i.e. .....:emailAddress) and it is working now