# SimpleSamlPHP / ADFS SAML 2.0

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, adfs3.0

I'm trying to integrate Simplesamlphp as a Service Provider with ADFS IDP. I've integrated this twice before with other clients, but now i'm getting an error I can't figure out.

This is from the Microsoft logs: 
`The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient SPNameQualifier: . Actual NameID properties: null.`

I have transient set as the `NameIDPolicy` in simplesaml. I've also tried the claims in this link [InvalidNameIDPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816803/adfs-2-0-invalidnameidpolicy). This worked for the other idp's but not this one.

Again, I have implemented this twice before with ADFS, and once with some third party solution. Not sure what steps to take next.  Any help appreciated.